# How to test a random color generator with jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have here a function that returns a **random Hex** color

```js
function randomHex() {
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).padEnd(6, "0")}`;
}
```

how can i test it with jest?
i want to know if it really returns a random hex or not

Comment: What do you want to verify about this function? Write a test for whatever that behavior is. BTW, the function appears to be broken without needing Jest to tell you: `randomHex() => '#NaN000'`. You probably mean to call `Math.random` instead of multiply the function itself by a number (hint: add parentheses).

Comment: i want to check if it really returns a random hex or not

Comment: What do you mean by "random hex"? How "random" do you want to validate it to be, exactly? If you want to validate that it's a hex, maybe use `expect(randomHex()).toMatch(/^#[a-f\d]{6}$/)` or something like that... but it's up to you to decide what you want to test... it's basically opinion-based if your question is "what behavior about this function _should_ I test?" And if the question is "how do I test behavior X?", you should unambiguously define what X means, then show an attempt at writing a test for it.

Comment: oh sorry i changed that to Math.random()

Comment: Break it into two parts.  One function that generates a random number, and one that generates a hex colour given such a number.  Test the latter only.

Comment: @Wyck the function is reasonable as-is. If you have to inject the RNG into this small function, it feels like the test suite is suddenly dictating the design in a way that seems to hinder its otherwise sensible functionality. Mocking `Math.random()` seems more reasonable to me, but this is a lot of work and feels like overkill, not to mention dips into an implementation detail.

Comment: To clarify, I mean "a lot of work" relative to the benefit (it's not that much work).

Comment: For random functionality I find it useful to test _properties_: every call should return a valid colour; but not every call should return the same value (otherwise `rerturn "#abc123"` would work). So call it multiple times and assert that: 1. you get more than one unique value; and 2. every value is a colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote myself, from [this post](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2021/Apr/10/js-tdd-api.html):

> So we can think about how to test it, here's a basic implementation of
> a coin flip:
>
> ```
> const flipCoin = () => Math.random() < 0.5 ? "heads" : "tails";
> ```
>
> We can be pretty confident that if we call this function a large
> number of times we'll get roughly half of each outcome:
>
> ```
> > Array(10).fill(null).map(() => flipCoin());
> [ "tails", "heads", "heads", "tails", "tails", "tails", "heads", "heads", "tails", "tails" ]
> ```
>
> but for a given call we can't be sure which it will be. So how can we
> write a test for that? We could reach for the facade pattern again,
> extract `const random = () => Math.random()` and replace that with a
> test double. This would work fine, but be very tightly coupled to the
> implementation:
>
> ```
> describe("flipCoin", () => {
>   it("returns 'heads' when the random number is less than 0.5", () => {
>     random.mockReturnValue = 0.3;
>
>     expect(flipCoin()).toEqual("heads");
>   });
> });
> ```
>
> One alternative is to write tests based on the *properties* of the
> implementation we want. For example, although we don't know the
> specific values, we do know:
>
> - It should always give one of the expected outcomes; and
> - It shouldn't always give the same outcome (otherwise `() => "heads"` would be a valid implementation).

In this case, a property-based test might look like:

```
describe("randomHex", () => {
  it("always returns a colour", () => {
    const colours = Array(100).fill(null).map(() => randomHex());

    colours.every((colour) => expect(colour).toMatch(/^#[\da-f]{6}$/));
  });

  it("doesn't always return the same colour", () => {
    const colours = Array(100).fill(null).map(() => randomHex());
   
    expect(new Set(colours).size).toBeGreaterThan(1);
    // or a higher number, but e.g. `.toEqual(colours.length)` can fail due to collisions
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
const { randomHex } = require('../../../');

describe('', () => {
  it('', () => {
    const firstRandomColor = randomHex();
    const secondRandomColor = randomHex();
    const hexRegex = /^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$/;

    expect(firstRandomColor).toMatch(hexRegex);
    expect(secondRandomColor).toMatch(hexRegex);
    expect(firstRandomColor).not.toBe(secondRandomColor);
  })
})
```

Comment: Collisions are highly unlikely but technically speaking `expect(firstRandomColor).not.toBe(secondRandomColor);` can potentially give a false positive.

Comment: That's fair. I'll argue the question was to test the current version of the function to confirm it works though, not alter it. Unless we have a truly working unique random generator, no testing strategy would work? Chances are slim, but *technically* even a while loop could go over eternally with a same result. Would the answer here be to update the original function, since it would otherwise work?

Comment: I agree. That's why I asked OP for clarification about what they actually want to test about the function. I can understand validating that it's returning a hex string, but it's not clear what "randomness" entails exactly. Mocking `Math.random()` lets you take it out of the picture at the cost of testing an implementation detail, and jon's answer makes it very unlikely probable, but the whole exercise doesn't seem to add much value to the testing suite one way or another.

Comment: Worth a peek: [How should I test randomness?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the extra reference. So ideally a unit test like this should work on an actual unique random generator, but it has no value because it's not realistic. I'll read more about statistical tests.